# Pandas Dataframe sampling does not produce similar distribution

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, distribution, sampling

I have two pandas dataframes:

df_1: Is my 'target' dataframe i.e. this (small) dataframe of ~100 rows represents the 'target' distribution of participants (which I collected myself) segmented by 'Country', 'Rating', 'Income bucket', 'Sector'

df_2: Is my development dataframe i.e. it is a much larger set of observations which I have 'been given from someone else's long term work' and contains ~32,000 observations, same segmentation

I am looking to sample df_2 using the distribution observed in df_1 so that df_2 'looks like' df_1 when building a model, so when i apply my model to df_1 I can assume similar effects

my dataframes look like:

```
participantId, sector, countryName, incomeBucket, Rating, group_no, weight
1, Retail, US, 250+, 10, 1, 10%
2, Retail, UK, 250+, 8, 2, 20%
3, Retail, FR, 50, 7, 3, 30%
...
```

weight is taken from df_1.value_counts() and mapped on i.e. group_no: 1 represents a Retail Sector, US Country, 250+ incomeBucket, and 1 Rating, and is observed 10% of the time in df_1, group_no = 2 is observed 20% of the time in df_1, and so on...

For completeness, in df_2, we observe group_no 1 ~50% of the time, 2 ~30% of the time and 3 ~ 20% of the time

```
my code - Attempt 1:
sampled_df = df_2.sample(
    frac=0.1,
    replace=False,
    weights='weight',
    random_state=2
)
sampled_df

my code - Attempt 2
sampled_df = df_2.sample(
    frac=0.2,
    replace=False,
    weights='weight_normalised',
    random_state=2
)
```

where weight_normalised = 'weight' / count(group_no) i.e. the sum of 'weight_normalised' would be 100% for the dataset, and 10% for group 1

My outputs do not give me anything remotely close to 10%, 20%, or 30% weight for group_no 1, 2, 3 it almost looks like it is in line with the weights observed in df_2 e.g. UK might be stronger in df_2, so we tend to see more of it

Thanks in advance for your help